# Opposite of innovation

Tags: antonyms

I received a newsletter from my University that read, "Are you promoting innovation, diversity, and excellence at [university name]?"

I was with a friend and we both saw the email on our phones. I quipped "Nope. I'm an agent of mediocrity, exclusion, and ..." but I couldn't think of a good antonym for innovation in this context.

What would a good opposite of innovation have been?

Answer (score 1):

I’m eager to scuttle any efforts to advance.  In this context the word you may be looking for:  backwards.  For a sentence like “Nope. I'm a backwards agent of mediocrity and exclusion.”

Answer (score 1):

The Merriam-Webster definition of [*innovation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/innovation) is:

> 1 : the introduction of something new
> 2 : a new idea, method, or device : NOVELTY

So, instead of promoting something *new*, you could be said to be promoting something *the same* as everything else.

In other words:

"I'm an agent of [**imitation**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imitation)."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> noun
> **2** : something produced as a copy : COUNTERFEIT
>
> adjective
> : resembling something else that is usually genuine and of better quality : not real

---

Alternatively, rather than talking about introducing something that isn't new, you could be talking about doing something that *takes away* from what already exists:

"I'm an agent of [**deterioration**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deterioration)."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : the action or process of becoming impaired or inferior in quality, functioning, or condition : the state of having deteriorated
> // rust *deterioration*
> // the *deterioration* of academic standards
>
> [*deteriorated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deteriorate):
>
> 1 : to make inferior in quality or value : IMPAIR
> // Exposure to sunlight may deteriorate the paint.

Answer (score 0):

### stat·ic

> adjective lacking in movement, action, or change, especially in a way
>   viewed as undesirable or uninteresting. (of a process or variable) not
>   able to be changed during a set period, for example while a program is
>   running.

---

Synonyms

> unchanged fixed stable steady unchanging changeless unvarying
>   invariable constant consistent uniform undeviating

### stag·na·tion

> lack of activity, growth, or development.

All the definitions are provided by the google dictionary extension.

Comment: "An agent of static" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

At the time, I used **traditionalism** but I felt that could have been improved upon. I thought there might be a more business-specific word that would be a better antonym for innovation.

---

> the upholding or maintenance of tradition, especially so as to resist change.

Answer (score 0):

"... the status quo"

> the existing state of affairs

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status%20quo)

I think it goes with the flow of what you're saying a bit more naturally than the thesaurus answers.

> Nope. I'm an agent of mediocrity, exclusion, and the status quo.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on how badly you want to oppose innovation. 
If you just want to dig your feet into the ground and stay where you are,
then [stagnation](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/481330/26083#481331) and [the status quo](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/481330/26083#481339) are good answers. 
But a true opponent of progress would want to *regress;*
to turn the clock back to the way things had been before;
to revert to things that have already been replaced. 
You would be an agent of ***obsolescence***:

> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/obsolescence):
>
>   **Obsolescence**
>   is the state of being no longer needed
>     because something newer or more efficient has been invented.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/obsolescence):
>
>   the state of becoming old-fashioned and no longer used,
>     especially because of being replaced
>     by something newer and more effective
>
> [ODO (Definition of obsolescent)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/obsolescent):
>
>   Becoming obsolete.
>   *‘the custom is now obsolescent’*

So, you can use a word that means that you’re impeding innovation. 
Or you can go above and beyond (below and beyond?)
and be an agent of ***obsolescence***.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***ruination***:

> The action or fact of ruining someone or something or of being ruined.
>   *‘commercial malpractice causes the **ruination** of thousands of people’*
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ruination)</sub>

It opposes *innovation*, which aims to create something new, by actively trying to ruin what presently exists.

> I'm an agent of mediocrity, exclusion, and ***ruination***.